# Can this filter be implemented using Sed?

Tags: awk, sed

I wrote a script to groom my .bash_history file, filtering "uninteresting" commands like `ls` from the persisted history.

(I know there's the `HISTIGNORE` variable, but that would also exclude such commands from the current session's in-memory history. I find it useful to have them around within the scope of a single session, but not persisted across sessions.)

The history file can contain multi-line history entries with embedded newlines, so the entries are separated by timestamps. The script takes an input file like:

```
#1501304269
git stash
#1501304270
ls
#1501304318
ls | while IFS= read line; do
echo 'line is: ' $line
done
```

and filters out single-line `ls`, `man`, and `cat` commands, producing:

```
#1501304269
git stash
#1501304318
ls | while IFS= read line; do
echo 'line is: ' $line
done
```

Note that multi-line entries are unfiltered -- I figure if they're interesting enough to warrant multiple lines, they're worth remembering.

I implemented it in Awk, but I've been reading about Sed's multiline capabilities (`N`, `h`, `H`, `x`, etc.) and I'd like to try it for this purpose. If nothing else, I'd be curious to compare the two for speed.

Here's the Awk script:

```
/^#[[:digit:]]{10}$/ {
  timestamp = $0
  histentry = ""
  next
}
$1 ~ /^(ls?|man|cat)$/ {
  if (! timestamp) {
    print
  } else {
    histentry = $0
  }
  next
}
timestamp {
  print timestamp
  timestamp = ""
}
histentry {
  print histentry
  histentry = ""
}
{ print }
```

Can this be done using Sed?

Comment: Do you know about `HISTIGNORE`?  https://superuser.com/questions/232885/can-you-share-wisdom-on-using-histignore-in-bash - you can `export HISTIGNORE=ls:man:cat` in your .bashrc and it will do something similar without writing any code.

Comment: @JohnZwinck Yes, but then those commands are ignored from the history in my current session as well. I frequently hit `up` or `ctrl-p` to recall a recent `ls` and tweak it, so I don't want to use `HISTIGNORE` in this case.

Comment: If you're a masochist, you might be able to implement in `sed`. Given you have a perfectly fine version in `awk` I would count my lucky stars and move onto other pursuits ;-) . The speed will not be of any significant difference unless  you're using Pentium 3 hardware ;-) . Just IMHO. Good luck to all!.

Comment: Thanks @shellter I know you're probably right :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure it can be done with sed. Here is an example using GNU seds `-z` option, which lets us deal with the whole file at once instead of working line for line:

```
 sed -rz "s/(#[0-9]{10}\n(cat|ls|man)\n)+(#[0-9]{10}\n|$)/\3/g;" yourfile
```

If everything works fine and you have a backup of your history file you might even use GNU sed `-i` option for inplace modification.

The `-r` options enables extended regexp, the `-z` option is explained in the manual like this:

> Treat the input as a set of lines, each terminated by a zero byte
>        (the ASCII 'NUL' character) instead of a newline.  This option can
>        be used with commands like 'sort -z' and 'find -print0' to process
>        arbitrary file names.

The basic idea is this: an uninteresting command is preceded and followed by a timestamp (or it is the last line in the file).

- the timestamp RE `#[0-9]{10}` is taken from your awk script
- `(#[0-9]{10}\n(cat|ls|man)\n)+` matches one or more of the the uninteresting  commands
- `(#[0-9]{10}|$)` the second timestamp is captured into `\3` (due to being in the third pair of parens) for reuse in the replacement part and the alternation `|$` fits the end of file case

Comment: Wow, that's actually much simpler than everything I had tried. I had to install gnu-sed since I'm on a mac and the BSD sed doesn't support `-z`.